# Run a continuous script as subprocess 1, until cycle in subprocess 2 is finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to write a Python code as a subprocess which will execute a continuous command in Linux shell until a cycle in subprocess two is finished.

This is the continuous command that I'm trying to run:

```
"while (true); do dd if=/mnt/DATA/random.dat of=/dev/null bs=128K iflag=direct >> /mnt/DATA/random.dat; sleep 0.2; done > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

I want that to keep running until something else is finished under another subprocess:

```
"for cycle in range(10)"

.

.

.
```

I am not sure exactly what I'm searching for because I don't know how to properly ask a question.

Comment: That's a very odd command to want to run... continuously read a file whilst discarding the output and also appending the output, of which there is none, to the input? Maybe you could clarify what you hope to achieve? And why you think you need Python to do it?

Comment: I would totally agree, as my colleague said "keep it simple".
I'm trying to make a tool which does the MMC stressing within a certain threshold on an ARM platform running a custom Debian distro. That command worked perfectly for me combined with:
**os.system("systemctl set-property ssh.service BlockIOReadBandwidth=\"/dev/mmcblk1p4 %sM\"" % read_threshold)**
which is executed in order to set the threshold before the initialization of the stressing command.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are trying to communicate between 2 separate processes; specifically when one wants the other to exit.

Traditionally, that sort of thing is done via a *"pid file"*, something like this...

Have the process reading the MMC write its own *"process id"* in a file when it starts. When the other process wants to stop it, it reads that file to get the process id and kills it.

```
# Write our pid to disk so other processes know which pid to kill
echo $$ > /tmp/stress.pid
```

Then, in the other process:

```
# Kill our friend
xargs -a /tmp/stress.pid kill
```

---

Another option might be to put both the stress test and the `for` loop in the same script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

stressMMC(){
   while : ; do
      echo "[stress] Thrashing MMC..."
      # dd if=... of=... 
      sleep 1
   done
}

# Run stress function in background and save its process id
stressMMC &
stressPID=$!

# Mainline code
for ((i=0;i<10;i++)) ; do
   echo "[main] Looping..."
   if [ $i -eq 5 ] ; then
      echo "[main] Killing stressMMC"
      kill $stressPID > /dev/null 2>&1
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
[main] Looping...
[stress] Thrashing MMC...
[main] Looping...
[stress] Thrashing MMC...
[stress] Thrashing MMC...
[main] Looping...
[stress] Thrashing MMC...
[main] Looping...
[stress] Thrashing MMC...
[main] Looping...
[stress] Thrashing MMC...
[main] Looping...
[main] Killing stressMMC
./go: line 22: 37291 Terminated: 15          stressMMC
[main] Looping...
[main] Looping...
[main] Looping...
[main] Looping...
```

---

Another option is to communicate via the filesystem, so here's a particularly ugly solution based on that!

In the process that is repeatedly reading from MMC, put a test inside the loop to see if a file exists, and break out, or exit if it does:

```
while : ; do
    [ -f /tmp/STOP ] && break
    dd if= of= ...
done
```

In the other process, simply create the sentinel file when you want to signal it to stop, using:

```
touch /tmp/STOP
```

Ugly, but effective.

Of course you can dress it up a bit:

- Remove the sentinel before you start in case there was a previous run
- Pass the name of the sentinel to each script as a parameter so you can do several things at once, each using different sentinel files